# Nested dictionary assignment, assigning to all sub-keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am pretty new to Python overall. I am trying to fill this nested dictionary (2 layers) dynamically, however for some reason when I assign a new sub-key, it assigns the same sub-key and values to all the primary keys `mykeys`. Is that expected? What am I missing?

Here is an example code:

```
mykeys = ["a", "b", "c"]
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(mykeys, {})
for n in range(10):
    for k in mykeys:
        sub_key = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")
        my_dict[k][sub_key] = n
```

I was able to get this working with `defaultdict` but I am curious understanding why the code above does what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes all the values of your dictionary to refer to the same [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) object:

```
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(mykeys, {})
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> `classmethod fromkeys(iterable[, value])`
>
> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

When you update one, the shared object will be updated:

```
>>> my_dict["a"][1] = 1
>>> my_dict
{'a': {1: 1}, 'b': {1: 1}, 'c': {1: 1}}
```

A trivial fix could be to use a dict comprehension instead of `.fromkeys()` so that you construct a new object for every key:

```
>>> my_dict = {k: {} for k in mykeys}
>>> my_dict["a"][1] = 1
>>> my_dict
{'a': {1: 1}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}}
```